# Dual Abelian scheme (relative Picard functor) vs Ext sheaf

Tags: sheaf-theory, duality, abelian-schemes

Let $A$ be an abelian scheme over some base scheme $S$. 
Let $A^\vee$ be the dual abelian scheme, defined as $\text{Pic}^0_{A/S}$ where $\text{Pic}_{A/S}(T)=\text{Pic}(A_T)/\text{Pic}(A)$. (maybe some assumptions are needed for this actually to be an abelian scheme again.)

My question:

I "know" that $A^\vee$ can be described as (or is isomorphic to) $\underline{\text{Ext}}(A,\mathbb G_m)$, at least that's what I've read quite a few times. I've never seen a proof and I don't know a reference. I don't even know how to define $\underline{\text{Ext}}(A,\mathbb G_m)$. Is it the right derived functor of $\underline{\text{Hom}}(A,\mathbb G_m)$? Could someone explain the mentioned isomorphism or give a reference?

Comment: The book "Commutative Group Schemes" by Oort, SLN 15, might contain what you ask.